# End Block VBA message

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code that I wrote. I don't understand why I keep getting the error message "end if without block if"....any suggestions?

```
Sub SaveTemplate()
Dim TempRow As Long, TempCol As Long
With Sheet1
    If .Range("E3").Value = Empty Or .Range("G3").Value = Empty Or .Range("E5").Value = Empty Then MsgBox "Please contact us with questions"
    Exit Sub
End If
If .Range("B3").Value = True Then 'New Template
        TempRow = .Range("D999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'First Avail Row
Else
    TempRow = .Range("B4").Value
End If
    For TempCol = 4 To 8
        .Cells(TempRow, TempCol).Value = .Range(.Cells(15, TempCol).Value).Value 'Bring down values from form into table
    Next TempCol
    .Range(TempRow & "." & TempRow).WrapText = False
End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Move `MsgBox "Please contact us with questions"` to a new line

Answer (score 0):

Write this on a new line:
`MsgBox "Please contact us with questions"`

The way it is written, it does not need the `End If`.